# How to determine the differences in parquet files

Tags: pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I'm storing a pandas DataFrame in a parquet file with this code snippet:

```
df.to_parquet(path, engine="pyarrow", compression="snappy")
```

As part of a regression test, I save the file and compare it to a previously generated file. I tried comparing the file contents in 3 different ways:

1. command line diff: the files are different.
2. pyarrow.parquet Table.equals: the tables are different.
3. Pandas assert_frame_equal(): the DataFrames are equal.

How can I dig deeper to find the differences between the parquet files?

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd

path1 = "f1.pq"
path2 = "f2.pq"

df1 = pd.read_parquet(path1)
df2 = pd.read_parquet(path2)

# This assertion passes
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)

table1 = pq.read_table(path1)
table2 = pq.read_table(path2)

# This assertion fails
assert table1.equals(table2)
```

Comment: It might be that the table metadata are different. Can you check `table1.replace_schema_metadata().equals(table2.replace_schema_metadata())` ? (in a next pyarrow version, there will be a `check_metadata=False` keyword in `equals` to make this easier)

Comment: @joris Yes, the test is indeed equal when metadata is removed: table1.replace_schema_metadata().equals(table2.replace_schema_metadata())

Comment: There may be a timestamp somewhere in the metadata.  If so, it would be nice if the equality test ignored the timestamp.

Comment: I am running over the same issue, and I am finding a difference of ~2MB in the size of the files. Knowing nothing about the parquet internals, I still find it hard to believe that a timestamp difference in metadata would lead to that file difference. The file diff startled my team, and rushed a debugging of a critical process until we found the dataframes were actually equal.

Comment: @N1ngu, the file size depends on the compression and the version of parquet you are using. Files with the same logical data don't necessary have the same size or binary representation physically.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I dig deeper to find the differences between the parquet
> files?

You can compare the metadata dictionaries and show possible differences using [`assertDictEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertDictEqual):

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
from unittest import TestCase
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3]})

def write_with_ts(df, filename):
    """Save df to filename as parquet with metadata with timestamp"""
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
    metadata = table.schema.metadata
    metadata.update({'timestamp': str(datetime.now())})
    table = table.replace_schema_metadata(metadata)
    pq.write_table(table, filename)

path1, path2 = 'f1.pq', 'f2.pq'
write_with_ts(df, path1)
time.sleep(1)
write_with_ts(df, path2)

table1 = pq.read_table(path1)
table2 = pq.read_table(path2)

# This assertion passes
assert table1.equals(table2, check_metadata=False)  # see (1) below

tc = TestCase()
tc.maxDiff = None   # show diff even if it's longer than 640 chars
tc.assertDictEqual(table1.schema.metadata, table2.schema.metadata)
```

The metadata assertion fails with:

```
...
AssertionError: {b'pa[420 chars]rsion": "1.4.2"}', b'timestamp': b'2022-06-17 17:14:00.410200'} != {b'pa[420 chars]rsion": "1.4.2"}', b'timestamp': b'2022-06-17 17:14:01.413461'}
  {b'pandas': b'{"index_columns": [{"kind": "range", "name": null, "start": 0, "'
              b'stop": 3, "step": 1}], "column_indexes": [{"name": null, "field_'
              b'name": null, "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "'
              b'metadata": {"encoding": "UTF-8"}}], "columns": [{"name": "col1",'
              b' "field_name": "col1", "pandas_type": "int64", "numpy_type": "in'
              b't64", "metadata": null}], "creator": {"library": "pyarrow", "ver'
              b'sion": "8.0.0"}, "pandas_version": "1.4.2"}',
-  b'timestamp': b'2022-06-17 17:14:00.410200'}
?                                    ^   ^^^^

+  b'timestamp': b'2022-06-17 17:14:01.413461'}
?                                    ^   ^^^^
```

(1) `check_metadata=False` is the default for `Table.equals()` since pyarrow version 0.17.0, see [ARROW-7891](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/6830).

---

Update as per comment:

The file size depends on *how* a table is saved to a parquet file. Take for instance a dataframe of 1M random doubles: `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.rand(1_000_000)})`:

- `df.to_parquet(filename)`: 8,281,466 B
- `df.to_parquet(filename, compression='GZIP')`: 7,800,448 B
- `df.to_parquet(filename, row_group_size=1000)`: 9,583,534 B

(default is `SNAPPY` compression and 1 rowgroup per 64M rows).
Other issues might be timestamp resolution in combination with Parquet version, see [`write_table`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html) for details.

You can get further insight by comparing the column metadata

```
metadata = pq.read_metadata(filename)
metadata.row_group(0).column(0) # etc
```

See also [Parquet file format](https://parquet.apache.org/docs/file-format/) for details on the file format.

Comment: How could that account for differences of up to 2MB in parquet files?

Comment: @N1ngu: metadata certainly won't account for substantial file size differences, but with knowing nothing about your data the reason is difficult to tell (what percentage of the initial file size is the 2MB?). See my updated answer for some more information/examples.